# Play video from NSData object in the documents directory

Tags: ios, nsdata

I am recording video using UIImagePicker, then trying to save it to the documents directory in NSData format.

This part works, but then I cannot play it back?  How do you get MediaPlayer to play an NSData object?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSLog(@"video url-%@",self.videoURL);

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];

NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];

NSString *videoPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.video.fileKey];

NSLog(@"video path-%@",videoPath);

[videoData writeToFile:videoPath atomically:YES];

self.videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

[self.videoController setContentURL:self.videoURL];

[self.videoController play];


}
```

Comment: Even copying the video to documents without converting it to NSData, the file will still end up as an NSdata object once in the documents file?

Answer (score 0):

Its OK I solved it.  Was not added the .mov file extension when naming the new path.